# Table not found, same using useTable

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I have a model, called "Cliente" and this model have a association with another table called ClienteRelFot. I declared that ClienteRelFot has a useTable = 'rel_fot_ec', but the cake are looking for "rel_fots".

The rel_fot_ec table  exists on my database because I use to find another data.

Someone have a idea to solve this problem?

I tried clear cache and delete all files from tmp folders.

Below, we have the error:

> Error: Table rel_fots for model RelFot was not found in datasource default.

Comment: Could you post you model association for 'Cliente'? Also, I'm guessing this error happens when you try to find 'ClienteRelFot' in a find from 'Cliente', not when you do a $this->ClienteRelFot->find)? Could you confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your associations are trying to pull data from the model 'RelFot' (per the error), not 'ClientRelFot', so declaring that 'ClienteRelFot' uses the table 'rel_fot_ec' will have no effect.

Try adding:

```
public $useTable = 'rel_fots';
```

in your 'RelFot' model.

Comment: Thank for your help!

I found the error, the model Cliente had a error on code, wherefore cake was looking a wrong table.

Comment: Not a problem.  If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as such (the checkmark) so that other users won't spend time trying to figure out an already-solved problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, even though using `public $useTable = ...`

My data model: **Event** *hasMany >* **Submissions** *hasMany >* **Authors**

Cake was telling me `[MissingTableException] Table authors for model Author ...`, the problem was not in the *Author* model, but in the *Submission* model:

```
class Submissions extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Author' => array(
            'className' => 'authors', // author should be singular
            'foreignKey' => 'submission_id'
        )
    );
```